# How to calculate temporal change over time when response is 0 or 1 in r

Tags: r, regression, spatio-temporal

What would be the best approach to calculate the temporal change in response that has values 0 or 1 over time? For example, I have data `df` with years `yr` and response `res` for a station A. How can I know if the change on response over time is positive (increasing) or negative (decreasing) or not change at all. what statistical tool would be better? This data actually shows the response of an atmospheric phenomenon on the extreme weather event as of whether the phenomenon was present when the extreme occurs or not.

```
df<-structure(list(yr = c(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 
1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 
1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 
1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010), 
    res = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), .Names = c("yr", "res"), row.names = c(NA, 
-61L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: So you want to know if the ratio of 0's and 1's is changing throughout the years?

Comment: yes.i want to know over the years if 0 has increased or 1 .

Comment: In that case you could build a simple linear model and check the slope term, if the slope is increasing and if it's significant.